# Static method is thread-safe if new instances are returned allways it gets called?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, application-pool

I have the following classes:

```
public class SesionPasoProxy
{
    private static EntitySerializer _serializer = EntitySerializer.Create();

    public static string Obtener(Guid idSesion, int orden)
    {
        SesionPaso item = new SesionPaso();
        item.Orden = orden;
        item.IdSesion = idSesion;
        return _serializer.ToXml(item);

    }        
}


 public class EntitySerializer
 {
      private EntitySerializer(){}  
      public static EntitySerializer Create()
      {
         return EntitySerializer.Create("Test");
      }

       public static EntitySerializer Create(string serializationContextName)
       {
            EntitySerializer  instance = new EntitySerializer();
            instance.Name = serializationContextName;
            return instance;
       }
       public ToXml(SesionPaso x){ return x.toString();}
}
```

Is that code thread-safe? SessionPasoProxy is used inside a ASP.NET WebForms aspx page. So it can get called concurrently.
As you see EntitySerializer is static but is returns new instances (not Singleton)
What do you think?
My unit testing is showing is thread.safe, but i am not sure at all.

Many thanks

Comment: _" SessionPasoProxy is inside a ASP.NET WebForms aspx page"_ Why you add this class to a page class, both are not related. Add the `SessionPasoProxy` class to it's own file. Apart from that, yes, it's thread safe

Comment: Hi, i edited. I wanted to say "is used inside". Why is thread-safe?

Comment: The method is thread safe, each time you call Obtener method, you create a new SesionPaso object, and you are not storing info in static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general static methods aren't more or less thread safe than instance methods. 
But if they only use local variables instead of fields it's likely that they are thread-safe(of course it depends on the methods used).

In your case `Create` is thread-safe because it always returns a new instance and no other (static) field was used which could be accessed from different threads at the same time.

But one thing: you should make `EntitySerializer.ToXml` static too instead of using the same instance in `Obtener`. It doesn't need to be an instance method:

```
public static string ToXml(SesionPaso x){ return x.toString();}
```

Then you don't need the `static` field `_serializer`(at least not for this):

```
public static string Obtener(Guid idSesion, int orden)
{
    SesionPaso item = new SesionPaso();
    item.Orden = orden;
    item.IdSesion = idSesion;
    return EntitySerializer.ToXml(item);
}
```

Comment: You are right. It´s legacy code , so I dont want to touch it. Only i am looking for a point the code is not thread-safe. Many thanks

Comment: You know some tool for checking thread-safe violation inside ASP.NET WebForms app?

Comment: You can try [Microsoft's CHESS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52619&from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2Fb23f8dc3-bb73-498f-bd85-1de121672e69%2F)

Comment: I downloaded it , but I think it  not very easy to use? I am right?